# Is there any way to convert string from pandas column to xml attributes?

Tags: python, pandas, xml, string

I'm having a bit of trouble modifying xml by converting string from pandas data frame to xml attributes.

This is a small part of my large XML file which still follows the appropriate format.

Input XML file(abc.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<brand by="hhdhdh" date="2014/01/01" name="OOP-112200" Insti="TGA">
<design name="OOP-112200" own="TGA" descri="" sound_db="JJKO">

<sec name="abcd" sound_freq="abcd" c_ty="pv">
<feature number="48">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>    
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="abcd" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
<per fre="psc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="ttt" value="1"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="89.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40mb" value="44.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70mb" value="77.00"/>
</mwan>
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745171" sound_freq="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSHHGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz">
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="77.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40mb" value="65.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70mb" value="94.00"/>
</mwan>
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745172" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907100" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
</mwan>
</sec>
#file continue....
</design>
</brand>
```

Input dataframe:

```
          name                      string                     
0               abcd    nan                   
1     M_20_K40745170    trt|z46565|trt|d222|trt|a234|hhh|abc    
2     M_20_K40745171    trt|zt54757|hhh|t65868|ggg|666t5
3     M_20_K407095555   trt|3333|trt|76767|trt|88876
```

I want to create attributes like for example:

```
<xyz db="trt" id="z46565"/>
<xyz db="trt" id="d222"/>
<xyz db="trt" id="a234"/>
<xyz db="hhh" id="abc"/>
```

for every name respectively.

Expected output(xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<brand by="hhdhdh" date="2014/01/01" name="OOP-112200" Insti="TGA">
<design name="OOP-112200" own="TGA" descri="" sound_db="JJKO">

<sec name="abcd" sound_freq="abcd" c_ty="pv">
<feature number="48">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>    
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="abcd" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
<xyz db="trt" id="z46565"/>
<xyz db="trt" id="d222"/>
<xyz db="trt" id="a234"/>
<xyz db="hhh" id="abc"/>
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
<per fre="psc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="ttt" value="1"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="89.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40mb" value="44.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70mb" value="77.00"/>
</mwan>
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745171" sound_freq="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSHHGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz">
<xyz db="trt" id="zt54757"/>
<xyz db="hhh" id="t65868"/>
<xyz db="ggg" id="666t5"/>
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="77.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40mb" value="65.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70mb" value="94.00"/>
</mwan>
</sec>


<sec name="M_20_K40745172" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907554" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
<xyz db="trt" id="3333"/>
<xyz db="trt" id="76767"/>
<xyz db="trt" id="88876"/>
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
</mwan>
</sec>
#file continue....
</design>
</brand>
```

Is there any appropriate way? I will post if I find anything.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get the a list of xml or string of xml. I put a carriage return in to show you can join with whatever you want. so whatever the equivalent html link break there is, you could use that.

```
def createxml(x):
    try:
        parsedlist = x['string'].split('|')
        print(parsedlist)
        cnt = len(parsedlist)/2
        print(cnt)
        xml_list = []
        for i in range(0, int(cnt), 2):
            xml_list.append('<xyz db="{}" id="{}"/>'.format(parsedlist[i], parsedlist[i+1]))
            xml_string = '\n'.join(xml_list)
        return xml_string
    except:
        return None

df.apply(createxml, axis=1)
```

string:

```
0                                                 None
1    <xyz db="trt" id="z46565"/>\n<xyz db="trt" id=...
2    <xyz db="trt" id="zt54757"/>\n<xyz db="hhh" id...
3    <xyz db="trt" id="3333"/>\n<xyz db="trt" id="7...
```

list

```
0                                                 None
1    [<xyz db="trt" id="z46565"/>, <xyz db="trt" id...
2    [<xyz db="trt" id="zt54757"/>, <xyz db="hhh" i...
3    [<xyz db="trt" id="3333"/>, <xyz db="trt" id="...
```

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Leon Thanks for help. but I observed that it is missing some pairs

Comment: what's missing? Using the input dataframe you provided (not the xml), it returns all the pairs.

Comment: it is missing some pairs in my case when I run this script on real data which is exactly similar. I had just add df['new_col'].apply(createxml, axis=1) to get all strings in dataframe

Comment: i see now. update the range to to this range(0, int(cnt)+2, 2)  --- add in the +2; the range upper limit wasn't high enough.  if that doesn't work on the real data set, you'll have to find the right way to capture what the upper limit should. you may want to just set it len(parsed_list) and see if that works.

Comment: Okay.. actually I am talking about some  strings in the row for example if I have string which has 3 pairs it is only printing 2, similarly if I have string of 4 pairs it is only printing 2 or 3 sometimes..maybe it is with splitting

Comment: it's how the function is iterating through the parsed data. the upper range wasn't set high enough. did you try  range(0, len(parsed_list), 2)? when i tried again with the data it worked.

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with your input xml (one of the `mwan` tags isn't closed and there's an inconsistency between your input dataframe and the values of the `name` attribute of the `sec` tags (there is no `M_20_K407095555` in the xml; there's a `M_20_K40745172`). But assuming these are fixed, I would approach it this way:

```
from lxml import etree
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

secs = """[your input xml above, fixed]"""
doc = etree.XML(secs.encode())
#extract the info from your input dataframe
df_list = df.values.tolist() #this assumes your input dataframe is called df
for l in df_list[1:]: #the first row in your input df is just noise
    dest=doc.xpath(f'//sec[@name="{l[0]}"]')[0] #we use f-strings to look for the <sec> which has the corresponding name attribute value; that's where the new elements will be inserted
    local_list = l[1].split('|') #extract the attributes and their values for this <sec>
    couples = np.array_split(local_list, len(local_list)/2) #split into attribute/attribute value pairs

    for array in couples:
        attrs = (list(array)) #convert to list
        ins = etree.fromstring(f'<xyz db="{attrs[0]}" id="{attrs[1]}"/>') #create a new element containing the new info
        dest.insert(2,ins) #insert it in the right place at the insertion point
print(etree.tostring(doc).decode())
```

The output should be your expected output.